# Is a Public IP necessary to send SSM commands to EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The AWS "run command" prerequisites page states that outbound internet access is required to run commands on instances. Instances with outbound rules allowing all traffic (0.0.0.0/0) that I have running, however, are not visible from EC2 Run Command in the AWS console. Am I greatly misunderstanding what is meant by outbound access? Do these instances need Public IPs before they can be sent commands?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not necessarily a public IP. The instance should be able to reach internet (for example through a NAT).

Your instance should allow all outbound traffic AND
able to access the internet through

- Public IP
- NAT
- Internet gateway
- some other means

The SSM agent needs reach out to AWS endpoints, so it needs internet access. A quick way to check this is to `ssh` into your instance and `ping` a well known site like `www.google.com`. If you cannot ping, then depending on your instance's network configuration (public subnet / private subnet), you may have to add an elastic IP or add a route etc.,